# No entiendo como funciona Or en python refiero al codigo siguiente

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-2.x

Alguien me puede ayudar por que y como funciona or en python debido a aque lo intente realizar segun la documentacion y me da resultados diferentes

```
import operator
operator.or_(2,8)
10

operator.or_(8,2)
10

8 | 2
10

2 | 8
10

2 or 8
2

2 | 8
10
```

gracias

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Operador lógico `or`

> *expresion* **or** *expresion*

El operador lógico `or` devuelve `false` si y solo si ambas expresiones son falsas, en caso contrario devuelve `true`. Ahora, en Python (y en muchos lenguajes) se compara de la siguiente forma:

```
false = 0
true = 1
```

entonces si pones cualquier número mayor a 0 el intérprete lo considerará como  `True`. Si utilizas el operador lógico or para cualquier cosa que no es booleana empiezan a ocurrir cosas inesperadas, por ejemplo al poner la sentencia

```
2 or 8
2
```

en este caso te devuelve el primer valor "True", por ejemplo:

```
False or 8
8
```

como recomendación, utilizar el operador lógico `or` solo en operaciones booleanas

Operador "or" bit a bit `|` o bien `operator.or_(2,8)` (bitwise)

> *número* **|** *número*

el operador bitwise esta pensado para trabajar normalmente con números, y básicamente compara bit a bit de los números, como ejemplo

```
2 es 0010
8 es 1000
```

entonces la comparación bit a bit con la lógica "or" (0 con 0 es 0, 1 con 0 es 1, 0 con 1 es 1 y 1 con 1 es 1) nos da lo siguiente

```
1010
```

que en binario es equivalente a 10. Como puedes darte cuenta, en operaciones bitwise el orden de los operandos es irrelevante, es por ese motivo que:

```
2 | 8 = 8 | 2 = 10
```

Comment: OK vale muchas gracias por aclarar esta duda estas pequeñas cosas evitan grandes inconvenientes

Comment: Una nota. El hecho de que el operador `or` te devuelva como resultado el primer término cuyo valor lógico sea `True`, se llama "cortocircuito", porque en ese caso no sigue evaluando el resto de la expresión `or`, pues ya sabe que será cierta. Ese cortocircuito se usa a veces para asignar una cadena por defecto a una variable si originalmente su valor era la cadena vacía o `None`, dejándola como estaba si no. Asi: `v = v or "defecto"`. No es muy recomendable, por ser poco legible, pero te lo puedes encontrar por ahi.